# Make IDE build output binaries to single folder, and resolve ref's from it

Tags: visual-studio-2008, msbuild, build-process

Our build server has been using the following properties for some time

```
OutputPath=c:\output;
OutputDir=c:\output;
OutDir=c:\output;
ReferencePath=c:\output;
AdditionalLibPaths=c:\output
```

Which make all output go to a common folder, and also allow resolving references for that same folder.  This works great because

1. it's an optimization over building
   locally and copying references
   locally
2. I need all my dll's in a
   common folder anyways so I can zip
   and ship

Since this is working great on the build box, I would like to bring the same experience to our developers.  I want our IDE builds to behave the same way.

In other words, I want the work flows our developers always use (build solution, build project) to behave just like I described happens on the build box.

I could easily accomplish this if I asked the team to create an VS.Net external tool to a batch file that just calls msbuild on the selected project with the desired properties.  But ideally they wouldn't have to change their workflow.

**I want to know**

- if anybody else is doing this?
- what is the best way to do it?
- do I need to edit every single csproj file or use an external tool or batch file

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need the OutDir and ReferencePath both set, for the projects to send their
output to OutDir and for them to resolve references from the same path. You could
add a common targets file with:

```
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003" ToolsVersion="3.5">
     <PropertyGroup>
           <OutDir>c:\output\</OutDir>
           <ReferencePath>$(OutDir);$(ReferencePath)</ReferencePath>
     </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

Put this in a foo.targets file, and import that in every project.

Answer (score 0):

We are doing the same. Editing every csproj file. Quite a lot of plumbing but it works.

If possible - try to reduce count of assemblies to minimum.

Edits needed for Csproj:

```
  <ProjectReference Include="..\Core\Core.csproj">
      <Project>{9C81B684-40CC-472A-804D-7C0F963315F5}</Project>
      <Name>Core</Name>
    </ProjectReference>
```

Should become as regular reference:

```
<Reference Include="Core, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,  
     processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
      <HintPath>..\..\Deploy\$(Configuration)\Core.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
```

Although - relative path to deploy folder should be defined as property.

But i'm not a build guru. Just sharing some info. :)

Comment: Could you provide an example of what you're editing everytime?  Could I do a bulk search & replace using grepWin for existing projects, then make a new project template?  I have > 500 projects so I have a high upkeep.

Comment: Oh my god... 500 projects. Then this might be not an option. Search&Replace tool would need to be too sophisticated.